# Application that calculates the first ten words of the sequence

Tags: labview

The sequence begins with a0=2 and follows the formula.

[image]

This is what I came up with, but I'm not sure if I got this right.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, short answer - it is not correct. Because, you do not keep track on `n-1` iteration value. You should use [shift registers](https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA03q000000YKYuCAO). And then, the solution to this task will be:

[image]